# Showing list of all 24 hours in sql server if there is no data also

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I need to show 24 hour calls for each day.
But I am getting the hours which I have calls only.

My requirement is I need to get all the hours split and 0 if there are no calls.

Please suggest

Below is my code.

```
    select  @TrendStartDate
    ,isd.Name
            ,isd.Call_ID
            ,isd.callType
            ,DATEPART(HOUR,isd.ArrivalTime)
    from [PHONE_CALLS] ISD WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE CallType = 'Incoming'
    and Name not in ('DefaultQueue')
    and CAST(ArrivalTime as DATe) between @TrendStartDate and @TrendEndDate
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe make a temp table with all numbers from 1 tot 24 in there, and then join to jour [PHONE_CALLS] table with a LEFT OUTER JOIN, so that you get every hour?

Comment: For help on generating your numbers from 0-23 for your hours the following series should help [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1), [part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2), and [part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3).

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: It would be great if you could show us some sample data and desired output.. I have a partial answer, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu added sample and output data in main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is that you use a table containing numbers from 0 to 23, and left join that to your data table:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 24 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) - 1 As TheHour
    FROM sys.objects
)

SELECT  @TrendStartDate
        ,isd.Name
        ,isd.Call_ID
        ,isd.callType
        ,TheHour
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN [PHONE_CALLS] ISD WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON DATEPART(HOUR,isd.ArrivalTime) = TheHour
    AND CallType = 'Incoming'
    AND Name NOT IN ('DefaultQueue')
    AND CAST(ArrivalTime as DATe) BETWEEN @TrendStartDate AND @TrendEndDate
```

If you have a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop), you should use that. If not, the cte will provide you with numbers from 0 to 23.

Comment: sys.objects will get locked. Never never use it to generate numbers in production, it will create problems.Use another table (as you suggest) or type the hours manually either with STRING_SPLIT or a UNION ALL:
SELECT TheHour = CONVERT(TINYINT, value) FROM STRING_SPLIT('0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23', ',')

Comment: ... or use `with(nolock)` hint, because here it can't do any harm. @JarleBjørnbeth good point, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numbers table you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT  d.Date,
        h.Hour,
        Calls = COUNT(pc.Call_ID)
FROM    (   SELECT  [Hour] = Number
            FROM    dbo.Numbers 
            WHERE   Number >= 0
            AND     Number < 24
        ) AS h
        CROSS JOIN
        (   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, Number, @TrendStartDate)
            FROM    dbo.Numbers 
            WHERE   Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @TrendStartDate, @TrendEndDate)
        ) AS d
        LEFT JOIN [PHONE_CALLS] AS pc
            ON pc.CallType = 'Incoming'
            AND pc.Name NOT IN ('DefaultQueue')
            AND CAST(pc.ArrivalTime AS DATE) = d.Date
            AND DATEPART(HOUR, pc.ArrivalTime) = h.Hour
GROUP BY d.Date, h.Hour
ORDER BY d.Date, h.Hour;
```

The key is to get all the hours you need:

```
SELECT  [Hour] = Number
FROM    dbo.Numbers 
WHERE   Number >= 0
AND     Number < 24
```

And all the days that you need in your range:

```
SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, Number, @TrendStartDate)
FROM    dbo.Numbers 
WHERE   Number < DATEDIFF(DAY, @TrendStartDate, @TrendEndDate)
```

Then cross join the two, so that you are guaranteed to have all 24 hours for each day you want. Finally, you can left join to your call table to get the count of calls.

**[Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d938c59861b01852bb400543dc122cf)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL SERVER recursivity with CTE](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) to generate the hours between 0 and 23 and then a left outer join with the call table
You also use any other Method [mentioned in this link to generate numbers from 0 to 23](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53801/1)

```
    set dateformat ymd
    declare @calls as table(date date,hour int,calls int)

    insert into @calls values('2020-01-02',0,66),('2020-01-02',1,888),
('2020-01-02',2,5),('2020-01-02',3,8),
    ('2020-01-02',4,9),('2020-01-02',5,55),('2020-01-02',6,44),('2020-01-02',7,87),('2020-01-02',8,90),
    ('2020-01-02',9,34),('2020-01-02',10,22),('2020-01-02',11,65),('2020-01-02',12,54),('2020-01-02',13,78),
    ('2020-01-02',23,99);


    with cte as (select 0 n,date from @calls union all select 1+n,date from cte where 1+n <24) 
    select distinct(cte.date),cte.n [Hour],isnull(ca.calls,0) calls from cte left outer join @calls ca on cte.n=ca.hour and cte.date=ca.date
```